# Automapper String to Enum

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Hi I saw many examples for this theme but each one that I tried did not work for me.
I want to map the Model from Dto on the post method and again reverse for the response.The model contains Enums but the Dto strings.Here is the problem:

> Type Map configuration:
> HistoryTransactionDto -> HistoryTransaction
> TransactionHistoryService.Dtos.HistoryTransactionDto -> TransactionHistoryService.Data.Models.HistoryTransaction
>
> Destination Member: TransactionType
>
> ---> System.ArgumentException: The value passed in must be an enum
> base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32. (Parameter
> 'value')

```
    public class HistoryTransaction
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }  

        public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

        public TransactionNetworkType TransactionNetworkType { get; set; }


    public class HistoryTransactionDto
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string TransactionType { get; set; }

        public string TransactionNetworkType { get; set; }


     CreateMap<HistoryTransactionDto, HistoryTransaction>()
                .ForMember(d =>
                    d.TransactionType, opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(source => Enum.GetName(typeof(TransactionType),
                    source.TransactionType)))
                .ForMember(d =>
                    d.TransactionNetworkType, opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(source => Enum.GetName(typeof(TransactionNetworkType),
                    source.TransactionNetworkType)));

var historyModel = mapper.Map<HistoryTransaction>(history);

var historyDto = mapper.Map<HistoryTransactionDto>(historyModel);

public enum TransactionType 
{
    Withdrawal, Buy, Send
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `MapFrom`, enum mapping is built in. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.